# Changing single values of variables

Tags: stata

I can't seem to find a way of changing individual values in Stata.. Say if I have a variable called `height` which has 20 observations, I can

```
dis height[20] /*displays the 20th observation of height*/
```

How can I likewise change say the 20th observation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Data Editor. Otherwise the command line syntax is `replace` ... `in` #. See the `help` for `replace`. If you keep a `log` either kind of change will be documented as a `replace` statement.

```
clear 
set obs 10 
gen y = _n 
replace y = 42 in 7
```

Comment: For those unaware, note that the use of `edit` from the command window serves as a quick way of opening the Data Editor. Also worth knowing the use of `ed` versus `br`.